# Let $f$ be analytic on $D=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<1\}.$ Then $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$ is analytic on $D.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic on $D=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<1\}.$ Then $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$ is analytic on $D$.

---

- ***My attempt***: Let $f$ be analytic on $D,~f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $u,v:D\to\mathbb{R}$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f$. Then $g:D\to\mathbb{C}:(x,y)\mapsto u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y).$ Let

$$g(x,y)=p(x,y)+iq(x,y)$$

where $p,q:D\to\mathbb R$ are real and imaginary parts of $g$ on $D$. Then

$$p:D\to\mathbb R:(x,y)\mapsto u(x,-y)
\\q:D\to\mathbb R:(x,y)\mapsto -v(x,-y).$$

Let $(x_0,y_0)\in D.$ Then

$$\begin{array}{ll}p_x(x_0,y_0)& = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{p(x,y_0)-p(x_0,y_0)}{x-x_0}\\ & =\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{u(x,-y_0)-u(x_0,-y_0)}{x-x_0}\\ & =u_x(x_0,-y_0)\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ll}q_y(x_0,y_0)& =\lim_{y\to y_0}\frac{q(x_0,y)-q(x_0,y_0)}{y-y_0}\\ & =\lim_{(-y)\to (-y_0)}\frac{v(x_0,-y)-v(x_0,-y_0)}{(-y)-(-y_0)}\\ & =v_y(x_0,-y_0)\end{array}$$

$u_x=v_y$ at $(x_0,-y_0)\implies p_x=q_y$ at $(x_0,y_0)$

Is it okay now?

Comment: You don't need to go through the limit definition if you just use the chain rule, but of course your idea works if you verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations (remember you have to verify both of them). For instance, 
$$
p_y(x_0,y_0) = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( u(x,-y) \right) \right|_{(x_0,y_0)} = - \left. \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,-y) \right|_{(x_0,y_0)} = - u_y(x_0,-y_0).
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a more direct approach (which I think is a little clearer):

We have $\frac{g(z+h)-g(z)}{h} = \frac{\overline{f}(\overline{z+h})-\overline{f}(\overline{z})}{h} = \overline{ \left( \frac{f(\overline{z+h})-f(\overline{z})}{\overline{h}} \right) } = \overline{ \left( \frac{f(\overline{z}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{z})}{\overline{h}} \right) }$.

Since conjugation is continuous, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
g'(z) &=& \lim_{h \to 0 }\frac{g(z+h)-g(z)}{h} \\
&=&  \lim_{h \to 0 }\ \overline{ \left( \frac{f(\overline{z}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{z})}{\overline{h}} \right) } \\
&=&  \overline{ \left( \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{f(\overline{z}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{z})}{\overline{h}} \right) } \\
&=&  \overline{ \left( \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{f(\overline{z}+h)-f(\overline{z})}{h} \right) } \\
&=& \overline{ f'(\overline{z})  }
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks. BTW I'm not sure about a step in my own attempt. Is it true $\displaystyle\lim_{(y)\to (y_0)}\frac{v(x_0,-y)-v(x_0,-y_0)}{(y)-(y_0)}=-\displaystyle\lim_{(-y)\to (-y_0)}\frac{v(x_0,-y)-v(x_0,-y_0)}{(-y)-(-y_0)}?$ Why?

Comment: Yes. Because negation is continuous. That is, $\lim_{y \to y_0} -\phi(y) = - \lim_{y \to y_0} \phi(y)$. (And the result of the limit is $-\frac{\partial v(x_0,-y_0)}{\partial y}$.)